# Dataframe Mean appending as a column using 2 separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as follows:

Dataframe 1:

```
Item    Start Date  End Date    Price   Mean Price
Item-1  21/12/2018  23/12/2018    15        ?
Item-2  22/12/2018  23/12/2018    16.5      ?
```

Dataframe 2:

```
Item    Date    Price
Item-1  21/12/2018  15.1
Item-1  22/12/2018  15.2
Item-1  23/12/2018  15.3
Item-1  24/12/2018  15.4
Item-2  21/12/2018  16.3
Item-2  22/12/2018  17.3
Item-2  23/12/2018  18.3
Item-2  24/12/2018  19.3
```

Based on the Item code and select the subset of dataframe 2 using start and end date from dataframe 1 and compute mean of price. Is there any process of doing this?

Final Outcome should be like:

```
Item    Start Date  End Date    Price   Mean Price
Item-1  21/12/2018  23/12/2018  15      15.1997807
Item-2  22/12/2018  23/12/2018  16.5    17.79297614
```

It might be a simple question but currently I'm unable to come-up with a good solution for this, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with for loop

```
l=[df2.loc[(df2.Item==z) & df2.Date.between(x,y),'Price'].mean() for x,y,z in zip(df1.StartDate,df1.EndDate,df1.Item)]
df1['Price Mean']=l
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, still learning from @Wen-Ben but here's another (expanded) way of doing this:

```
# Checking which dates falls in the range followed by taking the mean
res = []
for idx in df1.Item.unique():
    temp = df2[df2.Item==idx]
    idx_ = temp.Date[temp.Date.apply(lambda x: x >= df1[df1.Item == idx]['Start Date'].iloc[0] and x <= df1[df1.Item == idx]['End Date'].iloc[0])].index        
    res.append(df2.loc[idx_, 'Price'].mean())

# Assiging the result mean
df1.loc[:, 'Mean Price'] = res
```